# Moving an image to the right side of a paragraph

Tags: html, css, css-position

Good day folks,

I am struggling with this for a couple of hours now and could really use some good help!
On my website I am trying to move an image to the right side of a paragraph of text.

My code snippet:

```css
.innercontent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 3% 5%;
}

.snap {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.expitem {
    margin: 100px 25px;
    min-height: 300;
    padding: 15px;
}

.text {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="innercontent">
                <div class="expitem">
                    <h1>'Projectnaam 1'</h1>
                    <p class="text" >
                        'Projectomschrijving'
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="expitem">
                    <h1>'Projectnaam 2'</h1>
                    <p class="text" >
                        'Projectomschrijving'
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
                    </a>
                </div>   
            </div>
```

For compatibility reasons I do not want to use float, but if there is no other way, I guess I should have to deal with that. Thank you in advance for trying to  answer my question!!

Comment: *For compatibility reasons I do not want to use float* You mean browser compatibility? float is supported by all browsers.

Comment: I am aware of that, although sometimes it displays very odd layout in different browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using a grid system like Bootstrap for the layout, but for your code:

1. Use `display: inline-block` on the paragraph since you want to allow
   some space for the next item to come up on its line.
2. `vertical-align: top` to align the paragraph with the images as it
   leaves some gap above it.
3. In order to align on smaller screens, you need to reduce the width of the paragraph using media queries.

Notice that while reducing the screen size further, the images align to the bottom. This is the use case for responsive images to get in. Wrap the image inside a % width div and give `max-width: 100%`, `height: auto` for the image. As you can see, you will not face any above difficulties if you use any grid system.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/cv9qv6p9/)

```css
.innercontent {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 3% 5%;
}
.snap {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.expitem {
  margin: 100px 25px;
  min-height: 300;
  padding: 15px;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .text {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="innercontent">
  <div class="expitem">
    <h1>'Projectnaam 1'</h1>
    <p class="text">
      'Projectomschrijving' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
    </p>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="expitem">
    <h1>'Projectnaam 2'</h1>
    <p class="text">
      'Projectomschrijving' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
    </p>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the .text class by adding `display: inline-block` to it and that seems to push the image to right of the text on a full screen view for me (testing with Safari). Please check if that works like the way you want.

```css
.innercontent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 3% 5%;
}

.snap {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.expitem {
    margin: 100px 25px;
    min-height: 300;
    padding: 15px;
}

.text {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="innercontent">
                <div class="expitem">
                    <h1>'Projectnaam 1'</h1>
                    <p class="text" >
                        'Projectomschrijving'
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="expitem">
                    <h1>'Projectnaam 2'</h1>
                    <p class="text" >
                        'Projectomschrijving'
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
                    </a>
                </div>   
            </div>
```

Comment: Looks like Manoj Kumar beat me to hitting submit. I think his answer will provide a better view of the text along side the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem using bootstrap also.

```
    .innercontent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 3% 5%;
}

.snap {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.expitem {
    margin: 100px 25px;
    min-height: 300;
    padding: 15px;
}

.text {
    width: 50%;
}
```

html code with bootstrap

```
  <div class="innercontent">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="expitem">
                    <h1>'Projectnaam 1'</h1>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="text" >
                            'Projectomschrijving'
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="expitem">
                    <h1>'Projectnaam 2'</h1>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="text" >
                            'Projectomschrijving'
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda unde culpa, ratione exercitationem minus vel quidem eum blanditiis, nobis sint corrupti, neque, rem! Quod aliquid voluptates at consequatur, praesentium.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="screenshot" src="http://www.webactiv.ro/poze/portofoliu_c/vest_grup_install_2014.jpg" width="320px" height="270px" class="snap" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
```